# How to rebase on to an earlier remote commit?

Tags: git, rebase

I have a local commit `A` and I used `git pull --rebase origin master`, so now `A` is stacked on top of the latest remote master commit, but I realized that I didn't want to do that and needed to actually rebase on to an earlier vision of master.

I found the commit hash `earlier_commit_hash` associated with the earlier commit and did `git pull --rebase origin earlier_commit_hash`, but didn't seem to change anything (my local branch still includes all the remote master commits after `earlier_commit_hash`).

What is the proper way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: You could create a new branch (either local or remote) that has the earlier commit as `HEAD` and then rebase on that branch. I'd prefer the local branch in this case. Reason is to not leave any mistakes I might make on the remote to potentially impact others.

Comment: @LucasRoberts Wait, so say that I'm currently on local branch `current`. You're saying I should create another local branch `another` where `another`'s `HEAD` points to `earlier_commit_hash`, right? After this is where I'm not clear what to do. Are you suggesting I should then do `git pull --rebase another` while on my `current` branch? That would seem to run into the same issue as in my OP? Or are you suggesting `from another`, I should `cherry-pick` `A`?

Comment: I would follow the upvoted answer by ypnos, it is cleaner and fewer commands than what I was describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer commits from master are already part of your local history, this is why they will be carried over when you use `rebase` on the older commit. Note that they might still be rewritten with new hashes which makes the situation worse.

You could try `rebase --onto` instead. From the manpage:

```
       A range of commits could also be removed with rebase. If we have the following situation:

               E---F---G---H---I---J  topicA

       then the command

           git rebase --onto topicA~5 topicA~3 topicA

       would result in the removal of commits F and G:

               E---H'---I'---J'  topicA

       This is useful if F and G were flawed in some way, or should not be part of topicA.
```

So you can use the same mechanism to exactly cut-out all the commits between the reference on master and your branch-exclusive commits.

Comment: I'll try this, thanks. I combine `rebase` and `pull` into one command. Can I use `git pull --rebase --onto origin earlier_commit_hash`?

Comment: You would call `git fetch` and then `git rebase` instead of `git pull` to be able to use this option.

Comment: Got it, I'm going to try now. What does the tilde mean? I'm not sure why            `git rebase --onto topicA~5 topicA~3 topicA` "       would result in the removal of commits F and G:
"

Comment: Got it, I think I understand now

Answer (score 2):

If I were in your position and my branch was in your state, I would use [ypnos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71767365/184546) of `rebase --onto`. This is because it's probably the most efficient one-liner and I'm comfortable doing it.

That being said, another thing you could do which may be conceptually a little simpler is to look at your `reflog`, find the commit your branch was on before the rebase, and put your branch back to how it was before the rebase:

```
git reset --hard <previous-commit-id>
```

Now it will be as if you didn't do the first rebase, and you can go ahead and redo it with the commit ID you intended to use in the first place.